# AngularJS UI Bootstrap Carousel go to slide?

Tags: angularjs, carousel, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm new to this AngularJS thing, and I want to create a carousel with Angular UI Bootstrap. Is it possible to go to a specific slide by clicking an button?

http://plnkr.co/edit/X0Mr1sPUr5Je0tfkzgjy

Many thanks!

Comment: how did u solve  this @LiYinKong??  it is not working here http://plnkr.co/edit/F8ixwSIWsgbqLs7WCVuf?p=preview

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure. Each slide can have a bindable `active` property. You can use it to mark any slide as active. Here is an example in a plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/hvfaMFz4q1AlbOpuOwFv?p=preview

Comment: i thought i needed to set that property of the currently active slide to false, and this created a flicker. This solution is simple, thank you very much

Comment: @pkozlowski.opensource i checked in plunker , passing array no. 3 gives error ,its not working http://plnkr.co/edit/F8ixwSIWsgbqLs7WCVuf?p=preview

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if slides are static. Controller throws "$scope.slide is undefined"